# JSON DECODE PHP

Tags: php, json

Как записать в файл нужный элемент массива из JSON строки ?
Существует некоторый POST JSON от некоторого сервера:

```
{
    "Fed": {
        "status": {
            "value": "Number",
            "corp": "test"
                  }
           }
}
```

У себя на сервере делаю по классике:
**Данные приходят. Проверено.**

```
$json = file_get_contents('php://input');
$obj = json_decode($json);

file_put_contents("1.txt",$obj->status[0]);
```

В результате в файл пишется..ничего не пишется. Как исправить ?

Comment: Ну а ключ `Fed` кто впишет, Пушкин?

Comment: Пушкин в интернете, к сожалению, не написал, что нужно еще и Fed вписывать...либо я плохо ищу. Можно пример ?

Comment: Начните с `print_r($obj)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Нет никакого `$obj->status[0]`.

Надо либо `$obj->Feb->status`, либо `$obj->Feb->status->value`.

Comment: Большое спасибо.